# replace backslashes with forward slashes regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace backslashes with forward slashes in javascript with the replace function and regex but can't get it to work. Thought it would be the following but it doesn't work:

```
path.replace("/\\/g", "//")
```

If I had a path that looks like D:\Games\Scrolls\ what would the regex be to replace to D:/Games/Scrolls/?

Comment: Remove the quotes from around your regex as shown in the answers in the duplicate linked to your previous question. I.e., it should be `path.replace(/\\/g, "/")` - note also the replacement string should be `"/"` not `"//"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the regex pattern without a string type
    `path.replace(/\\/g, "/")`

Comment: Dangit was caught up in the normal text way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
path=path.replace(/\\/g,"/");
```