# Can't able to replace forward slash with backward slash

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```
var mystr = '\Data\Dashboard\myfolder\3.jpg';
mystr .replace(/\//g, '//');
```

It is removing all the slashes when i'm trying to replace. Can anyone tell me how to replace for this particular string.

End solution should be this `'/Data/Dashboard/myfolder/3.jpg'`

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace backslashes with forward slashes regex in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508990/replace-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-regex-in-javascript)

Comment: It doesnt work in my case. Please check it once @rick

Comment: it is not removing the slashes. have you try to console log mystr? backslash is a special char in JS

Comment: Your string does not contain any slashes, it only contains a few *(unnecessarily)* escaped characters. To insert a backslash in a string-literal you need to escape it with another backslash: `'\\'`. Your replace does nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `\` in your string which is considered as escape sequence ( You need to escape it ). see console.log

```js
var mystr = '\Data\Dashboard\myfolder\3.jpg';
console.log(mystr)

var mystr1 = '\\Data\\Dashboard\\myfolder\\3.jpg'; // Escaped '/' string
console.log(mystr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```js
    var mystr = '\\Data\\Dashboard\\myfolder\\3.jpg';
    var regex = /\\/g;
    
    var replaced = mystr.replace(regex, '/');
    console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: It is removing forward slashes

Comment: This will work as in path itself we were using \ then system treats as escape now it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function:

```
str.replace('\\', "/");
```

Comment: Edit your post instead of posting a fix as a comment.

Comment: Thanks @sjahan but when editing, it doesn't display the good answer : i wirte '\\' but display '\' in the initial post... but in the comment it do works...